# Event based trigger in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

For the below scenario where the left side is my source and the Right side is the destination:

```
Source                                                   Destination
----------                                               -----------------
sourceContainer/StaticFiles/Finance/X1.tsv               DestinationContainer/StaticFiles/Finance/X1.tsv
sourceContainer/StaticFiles/Customer/X2.tsv              DestinationContainer/StaticFiles/Customer/X2.tsv
```

I would want to place files at any of the source locations one at a time and it should trigger a copy pipeline to create path dynamically for destination.
I have used one copy activity in a pipeline where I have created triggers for each like Finance and Customer.

I have referred to the below link, but no luck
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger

Comment: "No luck" isn't clear enough, Can you share what you've tried and what the result was?

Answer (score 0):

We need use Get Metadata and ForEach activities to achieve that. I created a simple test to copy files and create path dynamically for destination.

1. First, we need to add a event trigger. Specify your container and path.
   [image]
2. Declare a dataset of your container.
   [image]
3. At Get Metadata1, select the dataset declared previously , then select Child items.
   [image]
4. At ForEach1 activity, add dynamic content `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` to the **Items**.
   [image]
5. Inside ForEach1 activity, we can define a Copy activity. Select Wildcard file path and add `StaticFiles` to the path.
   [image]
6. At sink tab, we create a dataset to the destination container.
   [image]
   Here is `output`. Then add dynamic content and type in `@item().name` . It will create path dynamically for destination.
   [image]

**Debug:**
The pipeline triggered when I upload a file to the `StaticFiles/finance` folder.
[image]
We can see it created path dynamically for destination.
[image]